# Jaro Winkler SQL Query for Related Addresses

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to return a list of related addresses to a datalist but I get errors when running this code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The error I am getting is "Invalid column name vaddress1"

**C#**

```
vaddress1 = txtchangeaddress1.Text;
string sConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sCon5"];
Connection = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
Connection.Open();
SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
String strSQL;
strSQL = "select distinct address1, dbo.fn_calcJW(vaddress1, address1) AS Expr1 FROM  address ORDER BY Expr1 DESC";  

OleDbDataReader dtReader;
objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, Connection);
dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();


//*** BindData to DataList ***// 

DataList2.DataSource = dtReader;
DataList2.DataBind();
```

**ASP**

```
<div id="addressMatch">
    <center>
        <h2> Do one of these addresses fit?</h2>
    </center>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <div style="margin-left: 0px; ">
                <table  width="100%" >
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" >
                            <asp:TextBox id="txtAddressMatch" width="240px" runat="server"  Font-Underline="True" BorderStyle="None" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="txtborder" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "address1") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>      
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList> 
</div>
```

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?

Comment: Easy with the downvotes!

Comment: Please use some sort of debugging tool (visual studio, firebug, etc) to determine ***what line is throwing that error***.  You do have to do *some* work here.

Comment: Yeah I know I am looking at it as we speak. I put this up yesterday and woke up to the downvotes. Trying to play catch up now and get to root of issue

Comment: Thanks for input jadarnel27.  The error is "Invalid column name 'vaddress1'" Trying the answer below and will report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you're getting the error here:

```
dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And, I imagine that the error is something about "vaddress1".  This is because you need to add "vaddress1" as a parameter to your SQL statement.  Something like this:

```
strSQL = "select distinct address1, dbo.fn_calcJW(@vaddress1, address1) AS Expr1 FROM  address ORDER BY Expr1 DESC";
OleDbDataReader dtReader; 
objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, Connection);
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@vaddress1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
objCmd.Parameters["@vaddress1"].Value = vaddress1;
```

---

Possible other reasons for errors in your code (this is not exhaustive, but since you didn't mention anything specific):

- `txtchangeaddress1.Text` is blank / null
- "sCon5" was not found in the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` collection
- Many possible reasons on this line: `Connection.Open();`

  - Your connection string is malformed
  - Your SQL Server is unavailable
  - You do not have the necessary permissions to access the SQL Server
- Errors in the stored procedure "dbo.fn_calcJW" are thrown on the line `dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();`

  - You're not actually adding parameters to the SQL statement.  This is the most likely problem, as it will mess up that call to the stored procedure.
- `dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();` returned no results, thus errors are thrown during the `DataBind()` call later

---

On a serious note, please include more information in your posts here than "I get errors when running this code".

Comment: Still getting this error after adding this solution. Could the problem be that this is a function and not a stored procedure? I am not sure the string strSQL is correct but not sure how to test it. The function works fine in sql server.

Comment: Yeah. Im thinking either the string or possibly order of events?

Comment: I figured out the issue. And it was the function that was causing the problem and it was the function. This helped me get to root of issue. Thanks man.

Comment: strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT  TOP (10) address1, dbo.fn_calcJW('1 ', SUBSTRING(address1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', address1))) / 2 + dbo.fn_calcJW('main', SUBSTRING(address1, CHARINDEX(' ',  address1) + 1, LEN(address1))) * 2 AS JW_score FROM dbo.Address ORDER BY JW_score DESC";